# How to set and understand fs.notify.max_user_watches

Tags: linux, sysctl

I don't understand the best way to set `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` with `sysctl`.  In fact, I don't understand much of what is happening here other than the fact that I need to set the number of files that can be watched by a particular process.

I believe that I can see the max number of users by running this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

My understanding is that some people suggest changing `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` by opening `/etc/sysctl.conf` in an editor and adding this to it:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Then run `sudo sysctl -p` to -- presumably -- process the changes made to the file.

Others suggest running commands like this:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

I know that `-w` stands for write, but what is being written and where? Is it just that this command changes `/proc/.../max_user_watches`?

Which of the two approaches outlined above is best? I understand that 524288 and 12288 are different numbers, but I don't understand the difference between the effect of running `-p` and `-w`.

Comment: Might be the wrong place to ask, but can someone point me to further information about max_user_watches.

Comment: @PaulOskarMayer https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#max-user-watches

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`sysctl -w` writes kernel parameter values to the corresponding keys under `/proc/sys`:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

writes `12288` to `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`. (It’s not equivalent, it’s exactly that; interested readers can `strace` it to see for themselves.)

```
sysctl -p
```

loads settings from a file, either `/etc/sysctl.conf` (the default), or whatever file is specified after `-p`.

The difference between both approaches, beyond the different sources of the parameters and values they write, is that `-w` only changes the parameters until the next reboot, whereas values stored in `/etc/sysctl.conf` will be applied again every time the system boots. My usual approach is to use `-w` to test values, then once I’m sure the new settings are OK, write them to `/etc/sysctl.conf` or a file under `/etc/sysctl.d` (usually `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf`).

See the [`sysctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html) and [`sysctl.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html) manual pages (`man sysctl` and `man sysctl.conf` on your system) for details.

Comment: I ran into an issue when running a Node/NextJS server to serve an app. The error said something about hitting a limit related to file watchers. After poking around on the Internet, I got things working with `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`. Do you know a downside to making this change that I should be concerned about?

Comment: Stephen to be clear, if the first code line works you then add (e.g.) "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288" as a line somewhere (anywhere) in /etc/sysctl.conf? Thanks!

Comment: @dez93_2000 yes, or better yet, `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf`.

Comment: Cheers muchacho.

Comment: @David I don’t know of any downside, I have that configuration on my systems.

Comment: @David Ironically, that's what brought me here, glad you asked.

And thank you Stephen for the breakdown to test using the `-w` flag; that's very useful. And for your helpful comment responses!

Comment: What might be a possible consequence for setting `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` too high?

Comment: @Noel you could [run out of memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#max-user-watches), but that’s extremely unlikely (and you’d run into other problems before that).

Answer (score 7):

```bsh
find /proc/*/fd -lname anon_inode:inotify |
   cut -d/ -f3 |
   xargs -I '{}' -- ps --no-headers -o '%p %U %c' -p '{}' |
   uniq -c |
   sort -nr
```

See the inotify count used.

Comment: This fails on RHEL6.8.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for sharing ... (works on Debian 11)