# sysctl -p failed on /proc/sys/pcie_aspm

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, sysctl

when we run the `sysctl -p` on our rhel 7.2 `server1` we get

```
sysctl -p
fs.file-max = 500000
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/pcie_aspm: No such file or directory
net.core.somaxconn = 1024

# ls /proc/sys/pcie_aspm
ls: cannot access /proc/sys/pcie_aspm: No such file or directory
```

but when we run the `sysctl -p` on other `server2` as

we get good results without error as

```
sysctl -p
fs.file-max = 500000
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
```

the file - `/proc/sys/pcie_aspm` not exist on this server also ( `server2` )

so why `sysctl -p` failed on `server1`?

Comment: What does `grep pcie_aspm /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/*` output?

Comment: I see now that someone add the pcie_aspm=off in the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As revealed in the comments, there’s a

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

line in one of the files which `sysctl -p` reads. This causes `sysctl` [to attempt to write to `/proc/sys/pcie_aspm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445011/86440); if that doesn’t exist (and it won’t, it’s not a valid [`sysctl` entry](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/), it’s a [kernel boot parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)), you’ll get the error shown in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter may be not supported by the kernel due to the inexistence of PciExpress subsytem.

Or it can be also the pcie_aspm is disabled.