# Contents of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is deleted after reboot

Tags: debian, ip, forwarding

I installed Debian 10 in VMWare. This Debian machine has to operate as gateway/router machine.

To enable ip forwarding between my LAN and WAN interface, I edited the value with nano in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward from `0` to `1`.

After rebooting the machine, the value is automatically restored to the value `0`.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how i can permanently store the value to `1`?

Answer (score 5):

[The `/proc` file system is a virtual file system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), which gives access to information and settings in the running kernel. The values it presents aren’t preserved across reboots.

To set a `/proc/sys` at boot, you can use `sysctl`; it will load settings from `/etc/sysctl.conf` and related files. Write

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf` in your case.

See [How to set and understand fs.notify.max_user_watches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444998/86440) for relevant links.