# Is it possible to use hibernation while not using swap on Linux?

Tags: grub

On Windows it is possible to use hibernation while not using any swap.

I wonder if this is possible on Linux?

Because on my Debian 11 I find this line in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... resume=/dev/mapper/luks-4205519b-f3fe-468f-b05e-44f25f6882a4"
```

As you can see the "resume=" option specifies the swap partition which is used for hibernation.

Now if I delete this swap partition (to disabe swap), what am I gonna write into /etc/default/grub?

Is it possible to use a hibernate **file** as on Windows?

Because I have 32GB RAM and if I use a 32GB swap partition only for hibernation it's a waste of space.

Comment: Maybe `swapiness` is all you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t hibernate without active swap on Linux, and in particular, whatever device or file you want to use for hibernation has to be enabled for swap when you hibernate.

You can hibernate to a file, at least on some file systems. The `resume` parameter needs to point to the device holding the file, and you need to add a `resume_offset` giving the offset to the file (which you can determine using `filefrag`).

You can ask the kernel to avoid using swap by reducing the swappiness value, [`vm.swappiness`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#swappiness). See [How to set and understand fs.notify.max_user_watches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444998/86440) for instructions on how to set that.

Comment: The swap file must at least have the size of the RAM (32GiB in my case) for hibernation?

Comment: No, you typically only need somewhere between a third and half of the memory in use.